# Java: Convert List<someType> to Map<someType, new HashSet<OtherType>>

Tags: java, java-stream, maps

I am currently trying to find a way of converting a List of some Type to a Map whose keys are the List elements and the values are an empty new HashSet of a different Type...

Is there some way of achieving this using streams and without using a loop?

Loop would be something like:

```
List<SomeType> xList = ...
HashMap<SomeType, HashSet<OtherType>> map = new HashMap<SomeType, HashSet<OtherType>>();
for (SomeType x: xList) {
  map.put(x, new HashSet<OtherType>());
}
```

What I tried so far is something like `Map<SomeType, HashSet<OtherType>> test = xList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, new HashSet<OtherType>()));` but this wont even compile and I am quite clueless about streams....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close with:

```
Map<SomeType, HashSet<OtherType>> test = xList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, new HashSet<OtherType>()));
```

But it is actually :

```
List<SomeType> xList = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<SomeType, HashSet< OtherType >> map = xList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i, v -> new HashSet<OtherType>());
```

The [Collectors.toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) expects a Function in both parameters. Instead of `i -> i` you can use `Functions.identity()` and instead of `v -> new HashSet<OtherType>()` you can use `HashSet::new` as follows:

```
xList.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Functions.identity(), HashSet::new);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
List<Integer> numbers = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Map<Integer, Set<String>> map = numbers.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, HashSet::new));
```